# Same width for table columns in outer and inner table

Tags: html, css

I have an outer table which contains all header names and multiple inner tables with all the data. Now I want to align the column width of the outer and inner table. Basically my html looks like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td>
      <td>Header 2</td>
      <td>Header 3</td>
      <td class="hide"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">Text for js library</td>
      <td class="hide">Text for js library</td>
      <td class="hide">Text for js library</td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Actual text</td>
            <td>Actual text</td>
            <td>Actual text</td>
          </tr>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see a demonstration in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o546s8g3/).

I know that it is a weird table structure but I have to keep it that way because of a javascript library I am using which needs that kind of structure. You can see that outer and inner table have the same width properties for each column but nonetheless they look completely different. The first line somehow does not take 100% width but all other lines do. What do I need to do to get a "normal" table look?

**Update**

I guess I just have to use percentage width statements.
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o546s8g3/3/

Answer (score 1):

I updated your jsfiddle for you, you can check https://jsfiddle.net/o546s8g3/5/

```
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:16.8%" >A</td>
      <td style="width:16.7%">B</td>
      <td style="width:16.7%">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td style="width:16.7%">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td style="width:16.7%">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td style="width:16.7%">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td class="hide ">se ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">Lorem</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td colspan="7">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>add ipsum dolor</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hide">dee</td>
      <td class="hide">dee ipsum</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem</td>
      <td class="hide">Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td colspan="7">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```

>
Some text below table

Basically, its just some calculations you need to do to make everything aligned